# giving delay function to output

Tags: programming

I want my arduino to give the output at a specified delay .The delay is calculated from a polynomial equation.

```
unsigned long t=40*Vin*Vin-760*Vin+4320; 
delay(t);
digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);
```

but while doing this i was unable to get the delay accurately while observing it through oscilloscope??

Comment: Delay does not accept negative values, where does Vin come from? Do you make sure t is always positive? Post some code so we can try help you better.

Comment: @bpinhosilva, that quadratic function is positive for all values of Vin that don't cause overflow. Its min value is t=710 @ Vin=9.5

Comment: What do you mean by "i was unable to get the delay accurately"? What do you observe and what do you expect instead?

Comment: You should consider putting the pin low again after some time, as you want to measure the time between pulses?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into using a hardware timer rather than using delay(), I suspect it will give you more accurate timing.

Timer configuration is not as straight forwards as using delay - they don't work in milliseconds or microseconds, but instead in multiples of clock cycles, which (I find) makes configuring them a little difficult to understand, but it is possible to set the interval of a timer within its own interrupt routine.

Another advantage to using timers is that your code can do other things whilst waiting between interrupts.

Have a read here for more information and simple examples:
http://playground.arduino.cc/code/timer1
or just Google "Arduino timers" for other examples and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you had in mind something like this fragment, which will raise `ledPin` for the time you calculated (in msec) then lower it again?

```
// ...
unsigned long t=40*Vin*Vin-760*Vin+4320; 
digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);
delay(t);
digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
// ...
```